# Is there an app that can turn off wifi for me when screen goes off?

Tags: wi-fi, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I have a [Kindle Fire HDX 8.9](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BHJRYYS). I have looked for a *WiFi Sleep Policy* (or similar) setting under *Settings -> Wireless & networks -> WiFi settings -> (menu button) Advanced* but there is none.

Is there an app available for this device that can set WiFi to turn off during sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [this simple app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ajas.screenoffwifioff&hl=en).

Comment: I have tried it. It seemed to work perfectly!